# What is a matrix whose components are basis vectors?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors, matrix-equations

TLDR; What is this thing: $\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z} \end{bmatrix}$?

---

I was thinking about basis vectors, and I wrote down a matrix product that I have not seen anywhere.

Suppose we have a position in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the vector $\vec{r}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$.

This vector is commonly given as a column vector, $\vec{r}=\begin{bmatrix}
 x\\
 y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}$

What I noticed was that if we chose our nouns for the mathematical objects such that certain matrix multiplications "just work out", I can write another form:

$$
\vec{r}=
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}
$$

What do I have to call the row vector so that this makes sense. I know it is not a "covector". Maybe it is a "fiber bundle" or some other "bundle"? I know in some notations, the "row vector of column vectors is a matrix", but I know there has to be a word for the "dual-covector-basisvector-matrix-thingy".

I did notice that with this form of writing vectors, the components of the form are "commutative" in the sense that "vector" is self-transpose or transpose invariant.

$$
\vec{r}=
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} x&y&z \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}\\ \hat{y}\\ \hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
$$

The transpose of one form gives the other form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}^T
=
\begin{bmatrix} x&y&z \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}\\ \hat{y}\\ \hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Computing the matrix product between the two gives back the original component form of the vector.

$$
\vec{r}
=
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} x&y&z \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x}\\ \hat{y}\\ \hat{z} \end{bmatrix}
=
x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}
$$

With other work I have done, I do know that this is more general than just this specific application and can generalize out more.

Comment: That's a dot (or inner) product: $x^T y$ where the row vector $x^T$ (for $x$ a column vector) reads "$x$ transpose".

Comment: I am not asking about the operation between the two matrices and am well aware of the dot product.

Comment: Maybe the concept of dual space of a vector space can interest you.

Comment: I think it's just a matrix which coefficients belong to a vector space. A matrix is just a rectangular array. You can store anything you want in a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
So your product
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Just reads as
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Or more simply
$$\mathbf{I}\boldsymbol x=\boldsymbol x$$
Your equation is just a statement of the identity transformation.

---

More technically speaking, this is cheating. The object $\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{e}_{1} & \boldsymbol{e}_{2} & \boldsymbol{e}_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$ is actually nonsense. The components of a tensor should be elements of a field. Vectors are not elements of a field.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but while an abuse of notation was the motivation for me writing it down, I have proven in my own notes that this object is more general than just "an abuse of notation"

Comment: I think google saw my post here and I did another search and this popped up:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra)#Formal_definition ; 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-frame ; 

I think the proper name for this is the ***frame "vector"***.